# Accessing the outer scope in Python 2.6

Tags: python, scope

Say, I have some scope with variables, and a function called in this scope wants to change some immutable variables:

```
def outer():
    s = 'qwerty'
    n = 123
    modify()

def modify():
    s = 'abcd'
    n = 456
```

Is it possible somehow to access the outer scope? Something like `nonlocal` variables from Py3k.

Sure I can do `s,n = modify(s,n)` in this case, but what if I need some generic 'injection' which executes there and must be able to reassign to arbitrary variables?

I have performance in mind, so, if possible, `eval` & stack frame inspection is not welcome :)

---

**UPD**: It's impossible. Period. However, there are some options how to access variables in the outer scope:

1. Use globals. By the way, `func.__globals__` is a mutable dictionary ;)
2. Store variables in a dict/class-instance/any other mutable container
3. Give variables as arguments & get them back as a tuple: `a,b,c = innerfunc(a,b,c)`
4. Inject other function's bytecode. This is possible with `byteplay` python module.

Comment: That's not how scoping works.  You ask to access a scope on a different stackframe.  It would be **very** confusing if scoping would allow what you try here, think of tail recursion being rewritten into loops.  So code optimization suddenly would change the meaning of a program, this never will happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **not** how `nonlocal` works. It doesn't provide dynamic scoping (which is just a huge PITA waiting to happen and even more rarely useful than your average "evil" feature). It just fixes up lexical scoping.

Anyway, you can't do what you have in mind (and I would say that this is a good thing). There's not even a dirty but easy hack (and while we're at it: such hacks are not discouraged because they generally perform a bit worse!). Just forget about it and solve the real problem properly (you didn't name it, so we can't say anything on this).

The closest you could get is defining some object that carries everything you want to share and pass that around explicitly (e.g. make a class and use `self`, as suggested in another answer). But that's relatively cumbersome to do everywhere, and still hackery (albeit better than dynamic scoping, because "explicit is better than implicit").

Answer (score 7):

Define the variables outside of the functions and use the `global` keyword.

```
s, n = "", 0

def outer():
    global n, s
    n = 123
    s = 'qwerty'
    modify()

def modify():
    global n, s
    s = 'abcd'
    n = 456
```

Comment: Replace `and` with `xor` for this to work. Rewrite from scratch for good advice.

Comment: He means "define them outside, or use `global`, but not both".

Comment: If you defined the variables in global scope *and* declared them `global` (as opposed to doing *either*), then it would, strictly speaking, work - but of course that's not a proper solution. (Edit: Just noticed I mixed things up... should be "replace `xor` with `and`" - iFail)

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes I run across code like this. A nested function modifies a mutable object instead of assigning to a `nonlocal`:

```
def outer():
    s = [4]
    def inner():
        s[0] = 5
    inner()
```

Comment: That's interesting. Ugly, but interesting.

Comment: You can type outer.s = 4, but that will assign an attribute to the outer() function. It is not the same as assigning to the local variable called s.

Answer (score 3):

Your options are to use [global](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) variables,

```
s = None
n = None

def outer(self):
    global s
    global n
    s = 'qwerty'
    n = 123
    modify()

def modify(self):
    global s
    global n
    s = 'abcd'
    n = 456
```

or define those as methods and use a class or instance variable.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = None
        self.n = None

    def outer(self):
        self.s = 'qwerty'
        self.n = 123
        self.modify()

    def modify(self):
        self.s = 'abcd'
        self.n = 456
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably also do this (not saying it is right);

define a function that returns an array with rows like so

```
["a = qwerty","n = 123"]
```

Then do in the scope you need the vars

```
for row in array:
  eval(row)
```

this is pretty darn hacky though.

Comment: I think you mean `exec(row)`; eval is for expressions only

Answer (score 0):

```
def a():
    i = 1

    def b():
        # i = 2

        def c():
            nonlocal i
            i = 3

        c()
        print('b:', i)

    b()
    print('a:', i)


a()
```

`nonlocal` will search in upper level scope, and go upper if not found

```
> python3 t.py
b: 3
a: 1
```

comment `i = 2`

```
> python3 t.py
b: 3
a: 3
```

Comment: The question is about Python 2.6 ;)