# Scope problem, can access object attributes but can't access the object instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a text adventure engine, the engine itself is working great but I am trying to implement custom events for game creators with callbacks. I have a `main.py` file that implements all of the game objects and builds the game. The problem is that I seem to be having trouble accessing the objects after I have instantiated them. have a look at this pseudo example code,

```
import engine

def build():
    # create new item objects
    key = engine.Item()
    door = engine.Item(a = 0)

    # set state of door
    door.locked(requirement = key)

    # CALLBACK FUNCTION
    def on_door_unlock():
        # ACCESSING THE ATTRIBUTE `a` IN `door` WORKS FINE
        door.a = 1
        # ACCESSING THE `key` OBJECT THROWS UnboundLocalError
        del key

    # assign callback to unlock event
    door.on_unlock(on_door_unlock)

build()
engine.run()
```

My file is obviously much larger than this but it is just as simple and this code isolates my problem. I am able to access the attributes of any object, but when I try to use del keyword on an object itself I get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'key' referenced before assignment`

- my callback function is written after the creation of the key object
- my callback is assigned to an event after the function is written
- I can access object attributes but can't access object itself.

everything seems to be placed in order. So what is the problem?
How can i write callback functions that can access instances of the objects I create?

Comment: `key` is not local (and `del` is not that idiomatic in Python because most people would ratter use a shared object or collection as a container instead of a function's namespace).

Comment: Then why am I able to access the attributes of `door` because it is not local either.

Comment: You can access it because scope in Python resolves according to the LEGB Rule (local, enclosing, global, builtin) but `del` is concerned only with the local scope.

Comment: `del key` means no more or less than "remove the name `key` from the **local** scope".  But this symbol has never been brought into the local scope of `on_door_unlock` and even if it had, removing it from there would not do anything to the scope of `build`.

Comment: This answers my stated question. This answers my question if someone would like to post an answer explaining this

Comment: If you're attempting to say "this key has been used, destroy it" you may need to this more in terms of a property of player, or the player's inventory, and reduce the "key count" to 0.

Comment: Probably a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763965/accessing-the-outer-scope-in-python-2-6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`del key` means no more or less than "remove the name `key` from the **local** scope".  But this symbol has never been brought into the local scope of `on_door_unlock` and even if it had, removing it from there would not do anything to the scope of `build`.

One of many better approaches would be to create an explicitly-named registry of objects, for example as a `dict` called `all_objects`.  Create the `key` inside it. Remove `key` from it by referring to it by name in your function.

```
ALL_OBJECTS = {}

def build():
    ALL_OBJECTS[ 'copperKey' ] = engine.Item()

    ...

    def on_door_unlock():

        del ALL_OBJECTS[ 'copperKey' ]
        ...
```